Integral of 4-form on $\mathbb{C}P^2$
Let $U = \mathbb{C}^2 \simeq \mathbb{R}^4$ and $U \subset \mathbb{C}P^2$ by $(u, v) \mapsto [1:u:v]$. Consider the differential form $$\eta = \frac{r^2d\theta + s^2d\psi}{1+r^2+s^2}$$
on $U$, with $(u,v) = (re^{2\pi i \theta}, se^{2\pi i \psi}) \in \mathbb{C}^2$.
Also consider the map $\kappa: \mathbb{C}P^2 \backslash [0 : z_1 : z_2] \rightarrow U$, $[z_0: z_1: z_2] \mapsto (z_1/z_0, z_2/z_0$).
Then it can be shown that $\kappa^*\omega = \kappa^*d\eta$ is the restriction of exactly one differential form $\hat{\omega}$ on $\mathbb{C}P^2$.
I want to prove the statement
$$\int_{\mathbb{C}P^2} \hat{\omega} \wedge \hat{\omega} = 1$$
I'm pretty new to differential geometry, so the first thing which came to my mind was
to use the integral definition and just start calculating. But the definition works
with a partition of unity and it seems quite complicated to actually calculate the integral this way.
Also i tried to calculate $$\int_U \omega \wedge \omega = \int_U d\eta \wedge d\eta$$ but i think this expression is divergent.
Therefore i think there must be some other way to calculate the integral...
I appreciate any hints or ideas :)

$\kappa$ seems to be mysterious to me. For instance, what would the image of $[0:1:0]$ be?

Yes, just corrected

@TedShifrin: dense is not enough, you need conull (or full-measure).

Yes, good point, @Moishe. Of course, that's what this is. I can't think of any practical situation with manifolds where what I said isn't sufficient. Is my off-kilter brain missing something obvious?

@TedShifrin: Yes, in practice, we always choose conull subsets. But there are situations when fractals appear when you do not expect them, like in the double suspension theorem.

Since $U$ covers all but a set of measure zero, you don’t need partitions of unity; just integrate over $U$. Are you sure the formula for $\eta$ is correct? I would expect $\eta=\partial\log(1+|u|^2+|v|^2)$ up to a constant.

Yes, that sounds sensible. But if we are talking about measure $0$ sets, what measure are we referring to?

@Jahi02, this issue is not that relevant, since the complement of your affine neighborhood has positive codimension, so the two integrations will necessarily give the same result.

The $\mathbb C^2$ in question is an affine coordinate neighborhood in the complex projective plane.  Its complement has complex dimension 1 (namely, it is a complex projective line), so certainly integrating over $\mathbb C^2$ will give the same result as integrating over the complex projective plane.
One may be able to avoid most calculations here by exploiting the fact that what is in the background is the Fubini-Study 2-form $\alpha$.  The 1-form you wrote down seems to be a potential for $\alpha$ (restricted to the affine neighborhood).  If $\alpha$ is normalized to be the generator of the image of 2-dimensional cohomology with integer coefficients in de Rham cohomology, then its wedge square (i.e., cup-square of the cohomology class) will be precisely the generator of the integer cohomology group of the complex projective plane.
By Stokes theorem, $\alpha^2$ will integrate to 1.  Explicit expressions for $\alpha$ can be found in Griffiths and Harris (or in my course notes here).
